# How do some people develop the tendency to overuse particular words?

Tags: word-choice, american-english

My ninth-grade history teacher said *ultimately* so much that a classmate and I started keeping tally each day.  He once said *ultimately* 26 times in a 48-minute period.

A co-worker's response to most things is the word *interesting*—seemingly as an acknowledgement. Often a response to any casual comment I make, or most work-related documents she reads aloud.

How is it that some people settle into using certain words so atypically frequently? It surprises me that they don't notice.

I don't mean this to be emotionally charged or meant to be subjective. I noticed it so I asked about it, and have simplified the question to reflect this.

Comment: Quityerbellyachinn!!  I've had coworkers whose every 3rd word was "fuck".  (I'm betting you have some annoying habits too.)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Qf6Sv3A9zs

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. But if you mean ***"pet phrase"*** here is the definition: ***"An informal term for an expression frequently used by an individual in speech and/or writing."***

Comment: Mostly we can't smell our own stink meaning we're oblivious to our own idiosyncrasies and those that spend the most amount of time with us (nowadays, that's co-workers, right?), are more than painfully aware of those idiosyncrasies.  We still talk about a co-worker who yawned so loudly throughout the day, we were sure he needed to light up a cigarette afterwards. :-)

Comment: This is a subjective question along the lines of "_____ sucks, am I right?" Please see the FAQ especially the section about what not to ask.

Comment: @MετάEd the question wasn't meant to be subjective or demeaning.  It's something I notice, and I tried to explain how I understand usage of a word to be.  I don't think those are unreasonable inquiries.  Edited to simplify

Comment: It should be noted that many people adopt a habit of using a particular word (or a selection from a small set of words) as their "uh" sound -- the sound they make when considering what to say next.  "Ultimately" (used as in interjection of sorts) is an obvious choice here.  The word "interesting" likewise might be the speaker's equivalent of "yes, I hear you", and serves a useful purpose of communicating that the prior utterance has been heard and is being considered.

Comment: Nominating to reopen. You might also check at [linguistics.se] to see if it has been discussed there.

Comment: And I have a doctor who attaches "as far as that goes" to most sentences, as far as that goes.

Comment: Your teacher ought to have become a politician!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the word is being used as a bit of a [filler word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)):

> In linguistics, a filler is a sound or word that is spoken in
>   conversation by one participant to signal to others that he/she has
>   paused to think but has not yet finished speaking. ... Among youths, the fillers "like", "y'know", "I
>   mean", "so", "actually", "basically", and "right" are among the more
>   prevalent. Ronald Reagan was famous for beginning his answers to
>   questions with "Well..."[citation needed], as President Barack Obama
>   often begins statements with "Look...".[citation needed] Fillers fall
>   into the category of formulaic language.

Answer (score -3):

Limited vocabulary and little guidance from peers, I suspect.

Technically, it is an interesting phenomenon, but ultimately impermanent.

Comment: classic response

Comment: I'm pretty sure this phenomenon has nothing to do with limited vocabulary. Most of the people I've encountered who have this are very well educated and have quite a large vocabulary. Do you have anything to back up your claims?

Comment: No, do you have any evidence for most people you've encountered being very well educated and having a large vocabulary? My suspicions were founded on as much evidence as you provided for your "pretty sure" ness.