# Sensitivity to overused words (actually, basically, literally,...)

Tags: redundancy

I've watched online a few (hours of) lectures, where the lecturer used actually and basically every other sentence.
I've developed a sensitivity to it, and now I can't stand these words.

This includes their derivatives and synonyms which, in the context being used, are fully redundant, out of place, or simply wrong.

It became grating, and I notice it everywhere, written or spoken. It feels like some kind of a disorder.

Has anyone heard of such a problem?
Any suggestions?
Not sure if I need a grammar or a medical forum.

Related link:
[How do some people develop the tendency to overuse particular words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293151/how-do-some-people-develop-the-tendency-to-overuse-particular-words)

Comment: The speakers are amateurs who are perhaps nervous, or perhaps so well-known that no one feels free to critique them.  You will be happier if you learn to ignore their weaknesses or simply avoid the speakers who offend you in favor of others.

Comment: Your question does not really seem to be one that's a good match for our site. People get annoyed about language all the time; this hurts only the person themself. Might try [interpersonal.se].

Comment: @tchrist It's not on topic for IPS because it's OP's personal problem, not an interpersonal one.

Comment: @Laurel I am reminded of Fry&Laurie's many word-aversion sketches. It's a personal problem but by no means an uncommon one according to [Language Log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4368).

Comment: I like "triggered" as proposed.  Also maybe you are "hypersensitive to verbal tics."  I refuse to listen to a speaker who overuses "like," so I can relate to your problem.  Are you a sensory avoider in general? Do you suffer from intrusive thoughts? / In the 60's there was a popular recording of someone overfocusing on his own tongue, who gradually got to the point of hardly being able to speak.

Comment: No intrusive thoughts. I'm, though, sensitive: noise, smell, light. Sounds like it's not a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are *triggered* by those words:

> **trigger** *verb*
> **3** : to cause an intense and usually negative emotional reaction in (someone)
>  // Water had a way of *triggering* my brother and making
> ordinary, everyday weather take a frightening turn for the worse. —
> Ingrid Law
>  <sub>Source:
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trigger)</sub>

That's one word for your sensitive reaction. You'll need to seek help for it elsewhere.

Comment: What's wrong with *bothered* or *annoyed* or *angered* or *aggrieved* or *freaked out* — you know, solid words that everybody knows what means without checking their hipster dictionary. :)

Comment: @tchrist - *Triggered* is commonly used by teens and young adults.